# Small footprint AC to DC converter

Tags: transformer, converter, buck-boost

I want to build a 3 kW AC to DC converter but the two-winding transformer is too big for my project. I want it to be small as possible. What are the possible options and their advantages and disadvantages?

The following are the options in my head.

1. Use an auto-transformer instead of a two-winding transformer
2. Use boost-buck converter after the rectification

Edit: 230 VAC 60 Hz to 380 VDC, at least 90% efficient, lower cost than using two-winding transformer.

Comment: I think there needs to be more information. Input and output voltages? Isolation? Line frequency? Efficiency? Cost? Environmental specs? Cooling? EMI regulations? This seems to be a switching supply so higher frequency will reduce size but may need exotic magnetic materials and may need fancy liquid cooling and other techniques.

Comment: I answer some of your question but I cant answer the others. Is having no isolation be a big down side? I dont see many using an auto transformer in ac dc converter. I have no idea on enironmental specs. Maybe I can use fan on cooling? Maybe I can use EMI Filter?

Comment: Surely you can find a commercial unit with specs similar to what you need, and use that as a starting point for fine tuning and miniaturization. You should be able to provide a maximum size as well, to see just how much work may be needed to meet your needs.

Comment: You need a switch mode power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Any straightforward AC to DC rectifier is going to have a bad power factor. At the 3 kW level, no supply company is going to appreciate a bad load like that. There have been regulations for consumer electronics for years now mandating a minimum power factor for loads above a few hundred watts.

You should have isolation, which is what a two winding transformer will give you, and an auto-transformer won't. To reduce the size, you would run the transformer at high frequency.

All of these considerations point to the same solution. Use a PFC corrected front end, followed by an isolating transformer and regulated boost to your output voltage. This need not be expensive, it's exactly the same block diagram as employed in every PC power supply, with a different voltage on the output.

Comment: If isolation is not required, any 3 kW switching supply with a PFC front end will have a DC bus of about 350-400 VDC. The rest of the circuitry is used to provide the isolated and regulated DC outputs. You could use eight 48 VDC power supplies with outputs in series to get 384 VDC. Each supply would be about 40 watts to get 3200 watts total.

Comment: [edit] The eight power supplies would have to be 400 watts each, so probably not very cheap, small, or practical.